# Flex List selectedIndex is -1?

Tags: list, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

I have a list in my flex application that has `requiresSelection = false` and `allowMultipleSelection = true`. I have run into a problem when I go to get the selected Index: it is returned as`-1`. I need to know what `Items` are selected in the list in order for my application to work. I have spent hours looking online and trying different methods to get this to work. Thanks in advance for any help.

Full List Code:

```
<s:List id="list1" x="10" y="35" width="100" height="400" allowMultipleSelection="true" click="list1Click(event)" 
contentBackgroundColor="#696969" dataProvider="{list1Array}" itemRenderer="assets.ListSkinClass"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

A selectedIndex value of -1 means nothing is selected.

If you have allowMultipleSelection = true; then selectedIndex will return the last item selected.

You can use selectedIndices to get an array of all the items currently selected.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the selectedIndex of the list once an item is selected. If I selected an item then the selectedIndex is equal to -1, but if I select two items then it will work fine...

Comment: Also, I have tried using selectedIndices but when I only select one item, selectedIndices returns null/"".

Comment: @RMK-Jacob Then something else is wrong with your code that cannot be determined based on the little code you have provided.  Or else, you found a bug in the List code. Can you provide a full runnable code sample to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @RMK-Jacob My best guess (from the code provided) is that you're trying to access `selectedIndex` before it has actually changed by listening for the `click` event. Try listening for the `change` event instead.